# about Hyperledger Fabric, how is the data passed to my Chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger

1:When I call the "Invoke" method, how is the data passed to my Chaincode?Can you post some primary functions?

```
{
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "method": "invoke",
      "params": {
          "type": 1,
          "chaincodeID":{
              "name":"mycc"
          },
          "ctorMsg": {
             "args":["invoke", "a", "b", "10"]
          }
      },
      "id": 3
    }
```

2:How and when the consensus service put data to database?

Answer (score 0):

The invoke is part of your chaincode.  You have to deploy your chaincode  You can call your chaincode via a REST API or   I recommend you take a look at [learn-chaincode](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/docs/tutorial_part1.md).

[1](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/docs/tutorial_part1.md): https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode and from there the marbles example here: [Marbles Example](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/docs/tutorial_part1.md)